# Ventana Modal para Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Quisiera que me digan como realizar un **modal en Windows Form** debido a que mi aplicativo se demora demasiado y que me muestre el mensaje ***cargando...***. No se si se podrá realizar, cuando concluya debe desaparecer el mensaje.

Comment: Hola Pierro. Sería bueno tratar de ser más específico. Tal vez incluyendo código relevante a tu pregunta y tu intento para resolver el problema.

Comment: Por otro lado, haciendo una busqueda en Google obtendras miles de resultados con ejemplos de como realizar lo que quieres. Trata de investigar un poco, intenta realizarlo y si te quedas estacado con alguna duda concreta, vuelve aqui y trataremos de ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución seria que insertes un Panel, lo pongas invisible (Propiedad Visible a False), le pongas la propiedad Caption a "Cargando..." y donde vas a realizar la tarea que se supone demora un tiempo, antes de ejecutarla pongas en panel alineado a toda la ventana y simplemente cuando termines lo eliminas de tu formulario o pones invisible nuevamente y problema resuelto. Siempre recuerda que de ser posible le des al usuario la posibilidad de cancelar la operación en curso.

Yo no desarrollo en vb.net, pero en Delphi por ejemplo sería algo como esto, luego de agregar un panel al formulario y asignarle como nombre panelMsg:

```
panelMsg.Caption := "Cargando...";
panelMsg.Align := alAllClient;
panelMsg.SentToFront;
panelMsg.Visible := True;
```

Una ves que terminaste la tarea, inviertes los pasos para ocultar el panel.

```
panelMsg.Visible := False;
panelMsg.SentToBack;
```

Ten en cuenta que estos códigos que pongo son para que tomes la idea simplemente de como deberias hacerlo tu en vb.net.

Comment: Sería bueno que añadieses el código de ejemplo implementando lo que propones. De esa forma la respuesta estaría más completa y el OP podría aprovecharla mejor o hacerte un comentario más concreto si no consigue solucionar su problema.

Comment: Ok lo tendré en cuenta.